# pytest-django: django_db_keepdb Does Not Prevent Destruction of Test Database

Tags: django, pytest-django

I am testing a Django (v. 4.1) application using pytest-django (v. 4.5.2).

I want to preserve the database that is created during testing so that I can examine it afterward.

According to the pytest-django documentation:

> django_db_keepdb
>
> > Returns whether or not to re-use an existing database and to **keep it after the test run**.

Here is how I am using it:

```
import datetime
import pytest
from annotations import import_data

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_import_data(django_db_keepdb):
    start_date = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)
    end_date = datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 1)

    import_data.import_data(start_date, end_date)
```

The test runs but pytest destroys the test database after the test run.

```
Creating test database for alias 'default' ('test_vita')...
PASSED                     [100%]Destroying test database for alias 'default' ('test_vita')...
```

Perhaps I am misinterpreting what django_db_keepdb is supposed to do?
How can I prevent the test database from being destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know so it will work or not but try this:
add this into the settings.py file

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'yourapp.tests.ClassName'
```

create test.py file

```
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner

class ClassName(DiscoverRunner):
    def teardown_databases(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```